# Is it possible to use an xbox controller for pitch bend/modulation?

Tags: midi

My friend just showed me his [Akai Pro MPK Mini](https://www.akaipro.com/mpk-mini-mkii) and I really like the pitch bend/mod joystick and I was wondering if it was possible to achieve a similar effect using the joystick on a game controller such as an xbox one controller. I like the capabilities a lot and would love to replicate the effect on a midi controller that doesn't have the joystick. I'm new to all of this stuff so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What has your research found so far? Why wasn't it suitable?

Comment: Oh man we did this in uni back around 2013. We created a theremin using a console controller as the controller. I can't remember how we did it now, though. If I got time, I may have a look for my uni work.

Comment: @n00dles - the interwebz is full of solutions to this problem, mainly for Windows. [OP didn't tell us what platform.]

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah not a lot of info or research. Can't find it anyway.